# How to parse this sentence? "Prices then gave way to concern driving activity will be reduced for days to come."

Tags: sentence-structure, parsing

I am having a hard time parsing this sentence from a [Longman Dictionary page](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/for-years-weeks-days-etc-to-come):

> Prices then gave way to concern driving activity will be reduced for days to come.

It seems a run-on sentence. Is the subject of the sentence "prices"? Then the verb is "gave way to"? What is the sentence's object then?

Comment: Prices then gave way to concern **that** driving activity will be reduced for days to come.

Comment: @Robusto Thanks. This helps. Is the omission of "that" here lawful?

Comment: Yes. It is lawful.

Comment: @Robusto OK, but then what is "driving activity"? I don't think the example makes sense. The best I can come up with is "Prices then gave way to concern, driving activity to be reduced for days to come."

Comment: *Driving activity* looks like a noun adjunct.  It's activity.  What kind of activity?  Activity about or involving driving.